# Select minimum from collection to include duplicates

Tags: c#, linqpad

I have a collection of 4 dutPdItems. I want to find the DutPdSeqNum with the lowest TotTfpRig to include duplicates.

I want to produce a linq query that finds the item number of the minimum value. This query should return a list.

If there are duplicate (as shown above), it should include all duplicate item numbers equal to the minimum value. The query should return a list.

The query should return a int list with DutPdSeqNum 2 and 3 in the list.

```
List<DutPdItem> dutPdItemList = new List<DutPdItem>();

DutPdItem dutPd1 = new DutPdItem()
{
    DutPdSeqNum = 1,
    FltTfpTot = 6.4m,
    RigDpMin = 0.0m,
    RigDhr = 0.0m,
    RigAdg = 0.0m,
    RigThr = 0.0m
};
DutPdItem dutPd2 = new DutPdItem()
{
    DutPdSeqNum = 2,
    FltTfpTot = 4.0m,
    RigDpMin = 0.0m,
    RigDhr = 1.55m,
    RigAdg = 0.0m,
    RigThr = 0.0m
};

DutPdItem dutPd3 = new DutPdItem()
{
    DutPdSeqNum = 3,
    FltTfpTot = 4.0m,
    RigDpMin = 0.0m,
    RigDhr = 1.55m,
    RigAdg = 0.0m,
    RigThr = 0.0m
};
DutPdItem dutPd4 = new DutPdItem()
{
    DutPdSeqNum = 4,
    FltTfpTot = 6.3m,
    RigDpMin = 0.0m,
    RigDhr = 0.0m,
    RigAdg = 0.0m,
    RigThr = 0.0m
};
dutPdItemList.Add(dutPd1);
dutPdItemList.Add(dutPd2);
dutPdItemList.Add(dutPd3);
dutPdItemList.Add(dutPd4);

dutPdItemList.Dump("DutyPeriod Item List");

var THRtoDistribute = 2.715m;

// gets the lowest duty period by total pay

var lowestDutyPeriodsByTotPay = dutPdItemList.GroupBy(x => x.TotTfpRig)
                                .Where(g => g.Count() >= 2)
                                .Select(y => y.Key);

// this query does not work, I cannot figure our why
var lowestDutyPeriod = dutPdItemList.Select(dp => dp.TotTfpRig == 
lowestDutyPeriodsByTotPay);                             


lowestDutyPeriodsByTotPay.Dump("lowest duty period");




}
class DutPdItem
{
    public int DutPdSeqNum { get; set; }
    public decimal FltTfpTot { get; set; }
    public decimal RigDpMin { get; set; }
    public decimal RigDhr { get; set; }
    public decimal RigAdg { get; set; }
    public decimal RigThr { get; set; }
    public decimal TotTfpRig => FltTfpTot + RigDpMin + RigDhr + RigAdg + 
RigThr;
```

I have figure out how to create the linq queries.

Here they are:

```
var minTfp = dutPdItemList.Min(dp => dp.TotTfpRig).Dump("Min Tfp");

var minDutPd = dutPdItemList.Where(dp => dp.TotTfpRig == minTfp).Select(dp => dp.DutPdSeqNum).ToList().Dump("Min Duty Pds");

var countMin = minDutPd.Count().Dump("count minDutPd");

var secondLowestTfp = dutPdItemList.OrderBy(dp => dp.TotTfpRig).Select(dp => dp.TotTfpRig).Skip(countMin).First().Dump("2nd Lowest Tfp");

var secondLowestDutPd = dutPdItemList.OrderBy(dp => dp.TotTfpRig).Select(dp => dp.DutPdSeqNum).Skip(countMin).First().Dump("2nd Lowest Duty Pd");
```

Comment: Is this set a HashSet or any collection?

Comment: this query will work on a collection (list)

Comment: Can you please post some sample code and the exact data structure here? What you have tried? What does not work? What problems are you facing?

Comment: Please [edit] the additional information into the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public struct IdAndValue {  // Example data structure
        public int id;
        public double val;
    }

    static IEnumerable<IdAndValue> findAllMinimums(ICollection<IdAndValue> data)
    {
        var byValue = data.ToLookup(d => d.val);
        return byValue[byValue.Min(grp => grp.Key)];
    }
```

To get a list, do `findAllMinimums(...).ToList()`.

Comment: `.Select(d => d.id)`